# SaveChanges() in EF Core called when it was not expected to be

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1, with EF Core and C#, in MS VisualStudio Community 2019, Version 16.7.7. In ConfigureServices() in Startup.cs, I have tracking turned off:

```
    services
      .AddDbContext<DC>(options => options
      .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DC"))
      .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(
          QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking));
```

I have a function for inserting a certain kind of record into the database, using LINQ to Entities. This function seems to work fine, and so does an exception reporting function that is called from a "catch" block in it.

In the "try" block, the insertion function calls dc.SaveChanges(), where "dc" refers to the DbContext.

In order to test the exception reporting function, I wrote the following line to generate an artificial exception:

```
    throw new Exception("Test A");
```

The insertion and reporting functions had the following patterns:

```
    public static void InsertRecord(DC dc, Record r)
    {
        dc.Add(r);

        try
        {
            throw new Exception("Test A");
            dc.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ReportException(ex);
        }
    }

    public static void ReportException(Exception ex)
    {
        ///
    }
```

When I called the insertion function several times on different Records in one operation, all Records except the last were saved to the database and the expected exception was reported on each one.

I did not expect any of the Records to be saved to the database. Should I have? If so, why?

Comment: It looks like you are passing a shared context into a static function.  Is it possible that the context's SaveChanges is being called elsewhere?

Comment: You can delete the code `dc.SaveChanges();` and see if it will add data to the database.

Comment: Does ReportException use the DbContext (DC)?   If the injected DC is used by other operations that later call SaveChanges() then `DC.Add(r)` will remain pending insert even if you've called an exception. A DbContext should be relatively short-lived, such as scoped within a using block for a given operation, or to a single request acting as an effective unit of work. Issues crop up when a context reference lives too long and queues up changes that you later expect to be aborted/rolled back only to find they get committed or cause exceptions when a later `SaveChanges()` gets called.

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful comments. The problem seems to have been due to SaveChanges() being called by another function that was called from the insertion function.